# bash debug options?

Tags: bash, debugging, error-handling

It seems to me (and correct me if I'm wrong please) that bash is quite bad at error messages that correctly tell you where the problem in your script is. For example, often I will get "bad EOF at line 953". What this *really* means is that there is a missing `fi` at line 127. Or, another classic is "-bash: line 60: syntax error near unexpected token '('". What this *really* means is that I have redeclared my function `mything() {}` as an alias at line 739 `alias mything=`, except that, the bash error points to line 60 where there is no actual problem (so it took me a while to find the culprit at line 739).

I tried to load the top hit 'bash debug' tool into VS Code and I was unable to get that to work (I press F5 to run, then a box appears saying "choose a debugger" so I select bash debug and nothing happens). I've tried an online tool that allows running code interactively and says that it can help with debugging, but that also did not help. I do some PowerShell and it does quite a bit better job at reporting the source of a problem. Are there ways (tools, or script analysis tools on github or online that can scan a script for issues like functions and aliases being redeclared with the same name and other tests like that) that enable us to debug bash scripts a bit better?

Comment: There's [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), but as a general rule, if you have bash scripts that are hundreds of lines long you should almost certainly be using a proper programming language and not a shell. The shell isn't made for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for shellcheck. I don't do extended logic with bash, none of my functions are more than say 30 lines long. There is utility in bash being "always there" and being the interface that I interact with a system, so I've never bought into that whole "bash bashing philosophy" of saying that bash is not a "proper language"; it has a lot of utility. I use other languages too (python, powershell, c#). My 1,000+ line bash scripts are sets of useful day to day functions that I use frequently.

Comment: To me, needing a shell script debugger is something that implies you're doing debugging far too late in the process. It seems that employing an iterative way of writing shell scripts may be helpful to you. Don't expect to write a script that does what it's supposed to do, all at once.  Instead, write an empty main loop and just make sure it iterates over the right things. Then add extraction of one piece of data, or whatever you need to do next, and make sure that bit works, testing after adding each new "feature" of the code.

Comment: I do all that, to the extent that I can, but over time, things happen, time constraints, jumping between projects. Unfortunately, "life happens", and things creep in, so debugging something is required in those situations.

Comment: The issues you are describing in the first paragraph are typical of all programming languages, e.g. C.  A missing round bracket will cause an error to be thrown many lines of codes later.

Comment: This is true to some extent, I have had many times scratching my head for an hour or more trying to fix such things in other languages, but it seems more so and more cryptic in bash. As I say in the OP, maybe I'm wrong and it's just a perception that I have, but any good debugging options are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this simple shell breakpoint-debugger in a german shell-scripting [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=jpm9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=echo%20-e%20%22dbg%3E%20%5Cc%22;%20read%20cmd;%20eval%20$cmd&source=bl&ots=zL53pitFnt&sig=ACfU3U0dBmPxDW4b0tVzQg5V3gPQoyD_gQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSjrSAprXzAhU2R_EDHcNxD7QQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false). You add the two following lines where ever you want to start debugging and step through by pressing enter or evaulate variables and functions at runtime.

```
read var    # set simple breakpoint
echo -e "dbg> \c"; read cmd; eval $cmd
```

run script

```
$ dbg> doSomethingFunction
$ dbg> echo $SOME_VAR
```

Alternatively using `set -x` and modifying the prompt variable `PS4` has helped me in the past.

```
PS4='+ ${BASH_SOURCE##*/}.${LINENO} ${FUNCNAME}: '
```